# Iterate in a collection attribute of an Object - Struts2

Tags: jsp, struts2

If in my Action class I have a new `BeanObject`

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
```

and MyObject has following attribute:

```
 private String type;
 private Collection<Animals> animalsList;
 ...
```

and the `Animals` has following attribute:

```
private Integer id;
private String name;
private String food;
```

I whant to iterate through the animalsList using Struts2:

```
<s:iterator value="obg.animalsList" status="listStatus" 
    <s:property value="id"/>
    <s:property value="name"/>
    <s:property value="food"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Is this a correct way to do that?

Comment: Apart for the typos (`obg` -> `obj`, missing end `>`), your code is right. It would have taken a lot less time to check it by yourself than to write a question asking us to check it for you, though

Comment: Did it work when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you using `s:iterator` tag the value attribute represents an OGNL expression which is evaluated against the context rooted to the valueStack. The action class is on top of the valuestack, so if you aggregate your object to the action class it will be searchable by OGNL.

But to be accessible it requires getter and setter for each field in the OGNL path.

You can learn more about [`s:iterator`](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/iterator-tag.html) and [how to get it working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28791492/573032).