# how to call action class from href tag of jsp page, and redirect to another jsp page with list of value using anotation

Tags: hibernate, struts2

i want to call action class from `href tag` from jsp and send the list of object to another JSP page. I got the isshu, data can not b display on jsp page i m write following code in struts2 and use following annotation

This is my jsp page, in which i want to call action class

```
<li>
  <a href="<s:url action='getallfranchiseax' />">View Executive List</a>
</li>
```

And the Action class is given below where the method return list of data in To CLASS

```
@Namespace("/Franchise")
@ResultPath(value="/")
public class FranchiseRegistrationAction extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<FranchiseRegistrationTO> 
{
    FranchiseRegistrationTO franchiseRegistrationTO=new FranchiseRegistrationTO();

@Action(value="getallfranchiseax", results={
            @Result(name="success", type="redirect" ,location="/Franchise/ExecutiveList.jsp"),
            @Result(name = "error", location = "/Franchise/FranchiseDashbord1.jsp"),
             @Result(name="login", type="redirect",location="/LogIn/LogIn.jsp?target=login-section")
        })
    public String getAllfranchiseEx() {
        FranchiseRegistrationService franchiseRegistrationService=new FranchiseRegistrationServiceImpl();
        List<FranchiseRegistrationTO> franchiseRegistrationTO=franchiseRegistrationService.getAllfranchiseExService();
        //System.out.println("----->"+franchiseRegistrationTO);
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Jsp page  given bellow to redirect the TOs value in **Executive.jsp** page.

```
<form action="getAllfranchiseEx" method="post" id="serviceForm">
<div class="card-content">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover"
    id="dataTables-example">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Full Name</th>
    <th>Phone Number</th>
    <th>Email Id</th>
    </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <div class="box-footer">
    <ul class="mailbox-attachments clearfix" id="imgli">
<s:iterator value="franchiseRegistrationTO"
    status="status">
<td><s:property value="fullName" /></td>
<td><s:property value="contactno1" /></td>
<td><s:property value="emailId" /></td>
</s:iterator>
    </ul>

    </div>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: plz hepl me....

Comment: You didn't define a problem or error.

Comment: i just want to iterate list of data on new jsp page on click of old jsp page href tag

Comment: You can see how iterator tag can be used to iterate a list of objects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28791492/573032).