# Get list from DB using stuts2

Tags: jpa, struts2

I have a list in Stuts2 and I would like to see it in the jpa I put the name of the list but I dosen't work and I dont recive any error

```
<s:iterator value="UserService.users">
        <tr>
            <td><s:property value="nom" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="prenom" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="username" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="password" /></td>
            <td><s:property value="tel" /></td>
        </tr>
</s:iterator>
```

---

```
public static void list() { 
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().
            configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").
            addAnnotatedClass(User.class).
            buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
    try{
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<User> users = session.createQuery("from User").getResultList();
        for(User u : users){
            System.out.println(u);
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();          
    }finally{
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28791492/573032

Answer (score 0):

A Struts 2 tutorial will save you some time; this is very basic and shows little effort.

Make `users` a property on the action and expose it with a getter.

```
<s:iterator value="users">
  <s:property value="nom" />
...
```